# Finding a point close enough to a point

Tags: python, euclidean-distance, closest-points

I have a problem with some peculiar characteristics.

I have:

- a point P (well in reality it is an array of points `ArrayP`, but the function I want to write is applied to each and every point, so it receives each time *one* point)
- an array of other points (which form a trajectory) `Trajectory`
- also the index of the first point in the original array.

Also the number of points in `Trajectory` is always bigger than the number of points in `ArrayP`.

I need to find the closest point in `Trajectory` to `P`

For example
[image]

My problem is that I don't know the indexes in `Trajectory`, only the index in `ArrayP`

Also the number of points in `Trajectory` is big so I prefer not to try all of them.

I have developed an algorithm that works well for some simple trajectories but it fails in some a bit more complicated trajectories still. Rather than posting it here and ask for improvements, I would like to hear a fresh approach on how to solve this problem

Comment: Are you only doing this once, for one specific point,or do you need to do these checks, with the same point set, several times for different points? For the simple former case, you could start with using a modified binary search along the trajectory.
The typical optimization for the latter case is data structures like Quadtree (Octree in 3D) or Binary Space Partitioning.

Comment: I am doing this for all points in `ArrayP`

Comment: Are the trajectories similar, or did they just coincide in the example?

Comment: They are somehow similar. However, `ArrayP` has less number of points and might be broken from time to time. Also they might cross sometimes

Comment: I have been recommended to use scipy KDTree but I have never used that and I don't know how heavy its use can be

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I prefer not to try all of them", is there really a need for this (i.e. would be too long to compute otherwise) or just your intuition ? Because otherwise this is a pretty straightforward problem, simply calculate the distances between all the trajectory points and each point in your array and return the minimum for each one.

Regarding the issue of not having the index of the trajectory points, you can simply use two variables to store the current nearest point and its distance and update it as you iterate through the trajectory points.